# How to read a file with a UTF-8 BOM using File.foreach in ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I would like to read a text file with a an UTF-8 Bom using ruby's file.foreach. The bom is inserted in the file by adding as first line:
`myFile.write "\uFEFF"`. 
Download the myFile.txt from this link:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b42363faaff561e7e3ca2edbe850d88d20190807164816/c6e4e1

I tried simply to read the file like this

```
  File.foreach(myFile).with_index do |line, line_num|
    puts "line = " + line
    puts "line.bytes = " + line.bytes.to_s()
    puts "line.bytes.map(&:chr) = " + line.bytes.map(&:chr).to_s()
  end
```

Problem is that line looks like empty every line of the file. However I can see there is something there using bytes. Also tried using encoding argument of File.foreach as follows

```
  File.foreach(myFile, :encoding=> 'r:bom|utf-8').with_index do |line,line_num|
    puts "line = " + line
    puts "line.bytes = " + line.bytes.to_s()
    puts "line.bytes.map(&:chr) = " + line.bytes.map(&:chr).to_s()
  end
```

But I am getting the same results. In both cases seems like ruby recognises the utf-8 bom because  `puts line.encoding` results in 'utf-8'. But I cannot access the chars of line string as usual. For example using myFile.txt the condition below is never triggered.

```
   if line[0,5] == 'Hello'
     puts "Hello catched"
   end
```

Do you know how can I read my files using file.foreach command?

Regards

Comment: please don't use wetransfer or other file hosting that is not readable before downloading.  Better off with https://pastebin.com/

Comment: _"a text file with a an UTF-8 Bom"_ – your file starts with `0xFF` `0xFE` which is the byte order mark for UTF-16 (little endian).

Comment: The fact that Ruby shows the encoding as utf-8 means very little. Ruby can very easily get the encoding wrong in which case that value is meaningless and you need to fix it yourself.

Comment: @lacostenycoder: I couldn't make that to work. You can create myFile.txt in ruby like this: myFile = File.new('myFile.txt', "w")
myFile.write "\uFEFF"
myFile.write "Hello\n"
myFile.write "I may contain UTF-8 characters as DøRBLAD\n"
myFile.flush
myFile.close

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have a file with mixed encodings of which we can't be sure of the source.  So determining how to "read" this data is not as easy as just convert it to whatever.  However, you might try this to see what's going on.

```
File.read('myFile.txt').encode("Windows-1252", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
=> "?Hello\nI may contain UTF-8 characters as D\xF8RBLAD\n"
```

This may not be a complete answer but you may want to refer to [this article](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/) which covers ideas about how to go about solving your issue.